# Drupal 9 Create User from contact the email field is hidden

Tags: user-account, user, drupal-9

Creating a user from a contact via actions menu brings form with hidden email field!??!
at *civicrm/contact/view/useradd?reset=1&action=add&cid=2572&cid=2572*
Why 2 CID?

Searching to find out where and how this is happening.. Worked last week..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The contact on the civi side needs to have an email address.